# Overflow with Swiper.js slider

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I always wonder how to achieve such an effect.
I'm using swiper.js and when I browse around I see things done like that with this library but I find it impossible.

How can I make the slides align to the left of the container but otherwise overflow?[image]

Comment: Can you post a code snippet ? Here is a link on how to do it https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/